WiFi Install no C Wire for thermostat or control panel
New home and trying to change old thermostat. New DIYer for electrical and HVAC. No C Wire however it does have 5 wires. RH, RC, Y, W, G.
Attached is the schematic on the actual unit. I am unsure how I would be able to wire a new thermostat without a C terminal. I have a Honeywell adapter coming in however I don’t know which wires to attach it to. Not having a control panel with terminals made this confusing.
The schematic shows only 4 wires but to my understanding and per the photos. RC and RH attach to the R line making it all one for the thermostat.
The white wire with 5 internal lines runs directly to the thermostat. The brown wire with red white and us used green come from outdoor unit.
Any help would be appreciated!





The Brown is the C wire

The (appliance-internal) Brown wire is your C wire.
To bring the C wire to your room thermostat, re-purpose the blue wire in the white cable running to the thermostat to be the C wire. Disconnect it from the red wire(s) and connect it to the brown and white wires (where the white is running to your outdoor unit).

If you repurpose the blue wire, which is correct, your old thermostat may need it's Rh and Rc terminals joined with a short piece of wire.   Your new thermostat will come with a metal jumper or switch that you should set that way if it's not the default.
